# JSONArray search

Tags: android, arrays, search

I have JSONArray in following format:

```
[
    {
     "id":11,"value":"36",
     "mSign":"Mesha","fSign":"Mesha",
     "desc":"Very Good"
     }, 
    {
     "id":12,"value":"33",
     "mSign":"Mesha","fSign":"Vrishabh",
     "desc":" Good"
     }, 
     {
     "id":13,"value":"16",
     "mSign":"Mesha","fSign":"Kanya",
     "desc":"Not Matching"
     }, 
     {
     "id":14,"value":"21",
     "mSign":"Mesha","fSign":"Dhanu",
     "desc":"Average"
     } ]
```

I am generating 'genid' from previous activity & want to compare it with above JSON "id".

But eclipse forcing me to convert JSONArray to array !

My question are

1. How to convert above JSONArray to array?
2. Is there any other easy method to do it?

Comment: Parse the JSONArray. Extract the id form it. And compare.

Comment: you can create a model class and the arraylist for the model class and parse it and then you can search with in the arraylist

Comment: `for(i=0;i<array.length();i++)
 {
   if(array[i].id=genID)
 {
 textView.setText("Value");
 }
 }
` I am Using  Above Code To Comapre

Comment: `if(array[i].id=genID)` looks buggy. Should be `if(array[i].id==genID)`.